# SQAlchemy timed row changes possible?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a db model:

```
class Alerts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Alerts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    alert_text = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True, unique=False, index=True)
    alert_timeframe = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=False, unique=False, index=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, unique=False, index=False, nullable=True, default=False)
```

Lets say a new message is received which matches the `alert_text`. This will trigger the alert `active` row to change to `True`. What i need to do is mark the `active` row as `True` once its received and once the `alert_timeframe` expires set it back to `False`.

I was wondering or actually hoping there is a way to do this with SQAlchemy for example when setting `active` to `True` make it a timed change which auto-reverts.

If it's not possible to do it with SQLAlchemy then what would be the best way to do this? Would the most efficient way be creating a function that would be called every time and keep track of the elapsed time? This is fairly easy to do but it seems very inefficient and i'm not sure how well it would work if there are multiple users and overlapping messages.

Any ideas are welcome and appreciated!

Comment: Is it required to store the active flag in the database? Maybe you can use a hybrid property to return the flag?

Comment: I think it is since i need to go back through it and find all active alerts at some point. I'm not sure what the hybrid property is so ill have to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use APScheduler to schedule the job to run at a specific date.
Use python datetime library to get current datetime, add timedelta of 10 minutes and then use that new date to schedule your function to run 10 minutes from now.

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.2/dateschedule.html

```
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, datetime(2009, 11, 6, 16, 30, 5), ['text'])
```